# Gnome shell extension to place icons wherever i want in the dock?

Tags: ubuntu-dock, gnome-shell-extension, favorites

I have the dock set to the right side of my screen.
What i want is to put the icons for applications(favourites) in the right corner (down).
By default i can only put applications in the dock in queue like fashion in which the first icon is at the top , and i can put more applications only after the first application's icon.

For example in this image, I want to put my Thunderbird Mail icon above the "Show Applications" Icon. (The right corner downside). Its easy for accessibility.

[image]

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Askubuntu!  I Suggest you look at this page:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1281812/how-to-change-position-of-show-application-on-dock    //Wishes!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

1. Open your terminal.
2. Type the following command `gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock show-apps-at-top true`
3. This should work !!