# How to change position of `Show application` on Dock?

Tags: 18.04, dock

My dock is placed at the bottom and the *Show Applications* button is at the right side of the dock.

[image]

How can I move the *Show Applications* button to the left side of my dock?

Comment: You can install gnome-dash-to-dock and/or gnome-tweaks, and then from there left click the dock(dots) and you can adjust the position of it /If that doesn't work You can try the super -> gnome-tweaks -> there you will find some settings to change it :)  Edit; Saw just now @aneeshnair's answer; I would suggest that one first. :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. Open your terminal.
2. Type the following command:

   ```
   gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock show-apps-at-top true
   ```
3. This should work to make the dock like this:

   [image]

Comment: This still works on Ubuntu 22.04